# Sending existing draft with node.js Gmail API

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, gmail-api

I'm attempting to use the [`users.drafts.send`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/send) API to send a Gmail draft which already exists. Despite a lot of searching I haven't been able to find a lot of concrete information about what the request should actually look like. The requests I've tried are:

```
gmail.users.drafts.send( { 'userId': user, 'resource': { 'id': msg_id } }, callback );
```

This results in a 'Not Found' error.

Based on some searching which seemed to imply that the [draft resource](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts#resource-representations) needs to be in a sub-object called `draft`, I tried:

```
gmail.users.drafts.send( { 'userId': user, 'resource': { 'draft': { 'id': msg_id } } }, callback );
```

That results in an "Invalid Draft" error. Which I suppose is a *better* error, but I still can't get it to actually send.

I've confirmed that the message ID and user ID strings are the correct ones, and there aren't any auth issues. (Other API calls are working fine.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first example is correct, but I think you are missing something.

I have a draft. I will [list it with the API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/list#try-it):

**Request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "drafts": [
  {
   "id": "1527269226973690353",
   "message": {
    "id": "1531f3452626f9f1",
    "threadId": "1531f3452626f9f1"
   }
  }
 ],
 "resultSizeEstimate": 1
}
```

As you can see, the draft has two ids. One regular `messageId` which will not work when doing draft specific operations, and the `id` which is the `draftId` you should be using.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize draft IDs and message IDs are different! I'll give this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

After searched in all the internet I found a solution:

```
gmail.users.drafts.send({ 
    auth: access_token,
    userId: 'me', 
    resource: {
      id: draft_id,
      message:{
        raw: base64encodedmessage
      }
    }
  }, callback);
```

This works even If you want to send a draft with new body